# Wingpanel not responding (Loki)

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

On a new loki installation I have the problem that the wingpanel stops responding after some time. I can then not open the applications menu, clock or indicators.

After a few minutes it sometimes comes back to life and everything works as expceted. Then it suddenly freezes again...

The only additional indicators I have installed is Dropbox.

Does anyone have an idea on how to debug this problem?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: A temporary workaround that works so far is to install and run `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere` and remove `wingpanel` from the `monitored-processed` setting. After a reboot wingpanel won't launch automatically. Open a terminal and run `wingpanel`. This way wingpanel doesn't freeze (running for 2 hours now), you just have to keep the terminal open...

Comment: **Nevermind.** The panel crashed and cannot be restarted again, even via terminal. Last console output: `Failed to register: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
`

Comment: When running the panel again via terminal it stops at `[AccountsService] act_user_get_user_name: assertion 'ACT_IS_USER (user)' failed`

Comment: Reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1623793

Answer (score 4):

[We narrowed the issue down](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1623793) to a single indicator, so the temporary fix is to remove it for now:

#### `sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-power`

I'll report back once the bug is resolved, but I otherwise recommend following [the report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1623793) in case more feedback is needed.

Comment: For a temporary workaround uninstall wingpanel-indicator-power: `sudo apt remove wingpanel-indicator-power`. Wingpanel will work after that, obviously without the power indicator.

Answer (score 1):

type **pkill wingpanel** command in terminal. it will restart the wingpanel