# Wingpanel Keeps Resetting on click

Tags: wingpanel, slingshot

Wingpanel keeps resetting whenever I click an application in slingshot, lock, logout, Alt+F2, Next Song, Etc.

However it's doesn't reset if I click "Applications" then type the app I want then press enter, and I can change the system volume without any problems.  But other that that it's being 100% useless.

I'm not an advanced Linux User However I do understand the basics, I've been using it on and off for about 5 years.  I'm not computer illiterate I have my CompTIA A+ it's just I'm trying to learn linux for my Linux+ and pentesting certifications(Also for it to become my default OS.  So I'll understand any explanations pretty well.

I tried to record it with gtk-recordmydesktop and kazam but however when you start recording they both go to wingpanel to stop so that didn't work out all too well.

How would I go about diagnosing and fixing this?

TIA, Kristi.

Comment: Are you on Loki (0.4, the latest release)? And have you tried http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7884/5565

Comment: Yes I'm on 0.4 Loki 

That didn't do the trick :(  This is the output from wingpanel: http://pastebin.com/csZJ7yD6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this issue after trying to turn on input-feedback-sounds with dconf

If your configuration value for `org.gnome.desktop.sounds.input-feedback-sounds` has been set to `true` then revert this change back to `false` to resolve the issue.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sounds false
```