# Top menu bar is disapearing

Tags: wingpanel, pantheon

I've a strange issue. After restarting my laptop, top menu bar is blinking and disappearing. I'm getting the below error If I run the command `wingpanel --toggle-indicator app-launcher`:

`[15:24:33.917940 GLib-GObject-Critical] g_object_new_valist: object class 'SecurityPrivacyPlug' has no property named 'supported-settings'
wingpanel: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/switchboard/personal/pantheon-security-privacy/libpantheon-security-privacy.so: undefined symbol: switchboard_plug_get_supported_settings`

Also, here is a screenshot:
[image]

What should I do to fix it?

PS:// Restarting my laptop, `apt-get upgrade` didn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wingpanel not responding (Loki)](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7680/wingpanel-not-responding-loki)

Comment: @wolf not sure.

Comment: @wolf In my case, it's not coming back to life, as written there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just applied updates via appcenter and had the same issue. Switchboad won't open either. I'm not sure if it's a new bug in switchboard-plug-security-privacy or what, but I was able to remove that switchboard plug to get everything working, well everything minus that plug.

```
 sudo apt remove switchboard-plug-security-privacy
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you solution. It's working now after removing it as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue only with the Daily PPA enabled where some related packages are not yet updated.

This is Danel's answer on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-security-privacy/+bug/1639357/comments/1

Comment: I removed the one from daily ppa and installed one from stable ppa, now working